# Python: how to extending the "ans = ops[op](*nums)" woking for more than two elements in nums

Tags: python, python-2.7

below is the background context of the question:

```
....
ops = {'+':add,'-':sub}    
op = choice('+-')    
nums = [randint(1,10) for i in range(2)]    
....
ans = ops[op](*nums)
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), which accepts a function and an iterable, and apply the function cumulatively to the iterable.

```
>>> from operator import add, sub
>>> from random import choice, randint
>>> ops = {'+':add, '-':sub}                                                       
>>> op = choice('+-')    
>>> op
'+'
>>> nums = [randint(1,10) for i in range(10)]
>>> nums
[7, 8, 1, 4, 10, 7, 10, 7, 10, 1]
>>> reduce(ops[op], nums)
65
```

`reduce(add, [1, 2, 3])` => `add(add(1, 2), 3)`

---

If you want to use `reduce` in Python 3.x, import it from [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce
```